# Laravel Forge NGINX Remove .php in paths

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, forge

I have an old legacy app (with about 900 URL's) that I've recently updated to Laravel, however the old paths are in `.php` format, like:

```
/some-path/here.php
/another-path.php
```

I need those to either rewrite (or just ignore?) the php part, not sure how best to do this with the default config I have from Laravel Forge Nginx.

```
    ...

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/www.sageaudio.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    ...
```

I guess there are 2 questions:

1. Is it better to do this as a 301 rewrite OR just do an internal redirect to index.php and pick it up with routing leaving the paths untouched?
2. I'm guessing I need to modify that `location ~ \.php$` block, but not sure what I need to change there for a rewrite or for routing to index.php.

Comment: I would recommend 301 personally because people's links will still work but they also get the opportunity to bookmark the new links and you can discontinue the old ones over time. (I'm assuming you prefer not having the .php in the URL)

Comment: Do files still exist at those URLs? Like on disk, is there still a `/some-path/here.php` file?